# override Textbox.OnClick on Windows Mobile CE

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I can't catch the `OnClick` event on a Windows CE application. The event `OnClick`,  `OnMouseDown` and so on does not exist. Is it possible to catch these events?

```cs
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClick(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseDown(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

this also does not work

Comment: I have never seen an OnClick event on a TextBox whatever technology used.

Answer (score 2):

You have to subclass the control and watch for the WM_LBUTTONDOWN/ WM_LBUTTONUP messages.  Subclassing is covered [in MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229681.aspx) and the CF team blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/20/420551.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/23/421143.aspx).  It's even covered (for a textbox click even) [on CodeProject here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TextBox_subclassing.aspx?msg=3291706).